# Problem with yarn dependencies and material ui component in AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, material-ui

I try to deploy my react app in AWS Amplify but i have this problem during the build :

```
2021-02-14T09:27:15.885Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
2021-02-14T09:27:17.657Z [INFO]: Failed to compile.
2021-02-14T09:27:17.662Z [INFO]: ./src/App.js
                                 Cannot find module: '@material-ui/core/Grid'. Make sure this package is installed.
                                 You can install this package by running: yarn add @material-ui/core/Grid.
2021-02-14T09:27:17.702Z [WARNING]: error Command failed with exit code 1.
2021-02-14T09:27:17.703Z [INFO]: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2021-02-14T09:27:17.708Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2021-02-14T09:27:17.708Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
```

The component '@material-ui/core/Grid' could not be found, i try to make a local build of the same code succesfully and i don't know why i have this in AWS.
My dependencies in package.json :

```
       "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
       "material-ui-core": "^5.0.1"
```

I really can't find any error on my code, so what is the problem ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by using

```
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

maybe it's different from using

```
yarn add @material-ui-core
```